# Changing some character shortkeys for visual studio or any text editor

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

how can i change some shortkeys on my keyboard ? for examle i prefer use alt + f for { this character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do it on an app specific basis, but the following should affect the whole system:

Look at the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` registry key.

Microsoft also have a tool to do this: *Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4*

Comment: after spend half hour or a hour ,i see that i couldnt implement it . already it is not support windows 7 but it should to work if it is support .net 2.0 . one time worked but not smoothly and didnt work in visual studio and in some of text editors .. but will look another keyboard layout programs . thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it myself so I'm not sure that it would work, but did you reboot after any changes. I think that's needed for anything to be picked up.

Comment: it doesnt require to reboot.because i can change layouts without it and works but new modified layout doesnt work as expected . it worked a few times on some textboxes just so :) strange . i am looking for another software which can create new layouts. wouldnt be great to use these short keys instead of ... alt + f for { and alt + j for } then alt+g for [ and alt + h for ] ... really this will speed up my typing abilities . even u consider it .

Comment: Yes man ... it works great on everything after a restart . it is absolutetly great tool for create your own keyboard layout ... thank youuuu